# Retrieving password from CyberArk using trusted certificate

Tags: cyber-ark

I am new to Cyberark password vault.  I have a node that has configured certificate based authentication with Cyberark server.  If I want to retrieve the password stored on the Cyberark vault using RestAPI from that node how to acheive the same.  I don't want to provide password to authenticate again.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to retrieve secrets directly from CyberArk's REST API for programmatic, non-human usage. It is recommended to utilize one of CyberArk's [Credential Providers](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/AAM-CP/Latest/en/Content/CCP/The-CyberArk-Application-Identity-Management-Solution.htm?tocpath=Get%20Started%7C_____1) to handle this process for you.

The Credential Providers have different means of allowing your application or script to retrieve the secret Just-in-Time using environment-specific attributes as authentication instead of requiring a secret-zero to retrieve them.

The REST API provided by CyberArk is to be used as a management API and not a secured API for secret retrieval.